# WPF Creating a template and binding to an object inside a property of a list item

Tags: wpf, object, binding, properties, datatemplate

My datastructure looks like this:

```
public class MyDataContext
{
    public ObservableCollection<Car> CarList {set; get;}
}

public class Car
{
    public Driver CarDriver {set; get;} // implements INotifyPropertyChanged (not shown here to keep it short)
    public string Color {set; get;} // implements INotifyPropertyChanged (not shown here to keep it short)
    public string Brand {set; get;} // implements INotifyPropertyChanged (not shown here to keep it short)
}

public class Driver
{
    public string Name {set; get;}
    public string Nationality {set; get;}
}
```

I'm binding CarList to a ListView in my XAML and I would like to create DataTemplates for both Car and Driver. My UserControl looks like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}>
        <StackPanel>
            <UserControl DataContext="{Binding CarDriver}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Color}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Brand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Driver}>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nationality}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CarList}"/>
```

The problem is that the ListView doesn't show the information of the CarDriver. I suspect my line

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding CarDriver}"/>
```

is incorrect, but I'm not sure what to put in instead...?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your UserControl. Do you use the DataContext in the right way? Take a look at [A Simple Pattern for Creating Re-useable UserControls](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/02/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight/).

Answer (score 1):

You should put a `ContentControl` like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CarDriver}">
```

and all will work fine. if not - try to put `DataTemplate` for `Driver` above the `DataTemplate` for `Car`